# Is here any quick way to check the syntax of latex?

Tags: math-mode, amsmath, syntax-checker

Here is recording many math questions so I want to have a way to check the syntax of latex especially under math condition. I checked ChkTeX, which could not satisfy me because it could not detect the syntax inside math environment. And I also tried to have \syntaxonly, and try to render it to have the latex report the problem but this way took 2 seconds for only one question because I had to use amsmath and amssymb packages to see the inside of math environment.
Do you have any idea to check the syntax under 100 ms for each question?

Comment: Have you tried `lacheck`?

Comment: you haven't given much indication about what the input looks like or what you did. If you are using commands defined in a package such as amsmath then any checker is going to have to read that package somewhere. The time taken to read the package should be negligible if you only do it once, for example make all your equations a single document rather than  start a new document for each.

Comment: @TeXnician haven't. Because I heard it did not update for a long time, did you use it recently?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle The input could be as simple as /frac{a}{b} or something like this. If I put all equations in a single document, is here a quick way to know which one is in problem?